# Additional scrollbar in a menu slow in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I have this page where I have a big menu that is scrollable with it's own scrollbar. The main scrollbar of the page is hidden which makes it not functional.

On chrome, this menu scrolls silk smooth and everything seems to be fine.
On firefox, the scrolling experience is horrible, it is just not usable. (Smooth scrolling disabled)

Is there something that could be done via css maybe to improve the performance of firefox scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, a similar problem regarding Firefox scrolling can be found at: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/981140

The corresponding solution, given by iamjayakumars states:

"Type about:config in the URL and filter general.smoothScroll.mouseWheel.durationMaxMS change the value as 1000 and try it.

If, it doesn't work try this

Type about:config in the URL and filter mousewheel.enable_pixel_scrolling and change the value as false."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for me but it would require all the users who visit the page to do it also. But I guess there is indeed no other option out there.